# Load SVG with PreloadJS for display in EaselJS

Tags: easeljs, createjs

When PreloadJS loads in an SVG via [LoadQueue(false)](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/PreloadJS/classes/LoadQueue.html), the result will be an `<object/>` as opposed to an `<img/>`.

It seems that the EaselJS [Bitmap()](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Bitmap.html) constructor will only display SVG loaded in as `<img/>`.

How can I either:

1. Get [Bitmap()](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Bitmap.html) to accept the SVG `<object/>` as loaded in in by PreloadJS.
2. OR get PreloadJS to load the SVG in as `<img/>`.
3. OR convert the SVG `<object/>` to `<img/>`

Comment: This is maybe not the answer you want to hear, but I'd recommend you to convert your SVG to createJS code using this method: http://tomkrcha.com/?p=3640

Comment: Hey olsn, I'm thankful for all suggestions! Looks interesting. Perhaps I'll be able to convince the designers to output using the Drawscript panel :)

Comment: You can also bring the SVG into Adobe Animate, which can publish to HTML (native EaselJS paths)

Answer (score 1):

"preloadjs": "1.0.1"

```
var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(crossOrigin = '');
loader.on("complete", onComplete);
loader.loadManifest([
    { id: "map", src: "map/monitor.svg", type: createjs.Types.IMAGE },
]);

function onComplete(e) {
    //画背景图
    drawImage(bgLayer, loader.getResult('map'), 0, 0);
}
```

[Unable to preload and display SVG with CreateJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608721/unable-to-preload-and-display-svg-with-createjs)